# Why when I tick the CoreAnimationLayer enable, the background color cannot be transparent?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, core-animation

I got a NSWindow and a NSView. In the NSView, I override the `drawRect` method like this:

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSColor.clearColor().set()
    NSRectFill(self.frame)

    self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, NSColor.redColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 200.0)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0) //start at this point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 500, 1000) //draw to this point

    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
 }
```

NSWindow is implement like this:

```
override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask aStyle: Int, backing bufferingType: NSBackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {

    super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: aStyle, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
    self.alphaValue = 1
    self.opaque = false
}
```

Here is the simulate result:
[image]

The colourful background is the wall paper, and which is transparent. So, I can see though the background. But here is what happen when I turn on `Core Animation Layer` in the NSView. It becomes gray color, which is not my expected. What's happening? Thanks. [image]

Comment: More information is needed. Is the drawing NSView the window's contentView? If not, does the window's contentView -wantsLayer == YES? I'm not entirely sure of this but you might try at least commenting out the line where you're setting the view's root layer's background color.